# Change CSS style on each div on collapse button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to know how I can change the style width on collapse button pressed or on child div collapsed.

**CSS**

```
.wrap-menu {  overflow:hidden; display:block; width:310px;}
```

this is the style. When it is not collapsed I would like the `width:0px;` when collapsed to changed to `width:310px;`

**This is my code:**

```
<a href="#" class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#sub-menu-invest">
<div class="wrap-menu">
<div class="menu-left"><span class="icon"></span></div>
<div class="collapse width right-collapse">
<div class="menu-right">Section<span class="panel-heading pull-right"></span></div>                     
</div>
</div>
</a>

<div id="sub-menu-invest" class="collapse">
<a href="#">
<div class="wrap-menu">
<div class="menu-left menu-dropdown background-inside"><svg></svg></div>
<div class="collapse width right-collapse">
<div class="menu-right menu-dropdown background-inside">Section Inside</div>
</div>
</div>
</a>
```

So when DIV `id="sub-menu-invest"`  is collapsed the width of wrap-menu to be 310px when it is not collapsed to change to `width:0px;`

Live example can be seen here: http://www.emocool.com/test/menu/index.html

Comment: What does the collapsing?

Comment: vertical collapse of the div: menu-right. For this reason the menu container is overlapping the content when it is collapsed and when it is not collapsed. So I want to make the container with:0px when it is not collapsed to not overtake the right container.

Comment: are you using jquery to collapse the menu? can you post function where the actual collapsing of the div happens?

Comment: had to understand what you want, you should create a fiddle and explain what you expect to happen

Comment: no I am using twitter-bootstrap collapse

Comment: Sorry, it's hard to understand the desired behaviour. There are multiple ways to activate the menu on your page (Test button, menu icon in the top left corner). I don't know which one you're talking about. Please try to isolate the problem. That said, when you activate the menu, the wrapper `a` tag gains a CSS class `.collapsed`. You can add extra style `.collapsed .wrap-menu{width:0px!important}`